# What HTML element can I hold a string of javascript code without the browser evaluating it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following code:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '12345'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12345&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Which is stored as a string in my webserver and is being encoded by json as the following:

```
In [3]: json.dumps(a)
Out[3]: '"\\n<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->\\n<script>\\n!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?\\nn.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;\\nn.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version=\'2.0\';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;\\nt.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,\\ndocument,\'script\',\'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js\');\\nfbq(\'init\', \'12345\'); // Insert your pixel ID here.\\nfbq(\'track\', \'PageView\');\\n</script>\\n<noscript><img height=\\"1\\" width=\\"1\\" style=\\"display:none\\"\\nsrc=\\"https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12345&ev=PageView&noscript=1\\"\\n/></noscript>\\n<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->\\n<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->\\n"'
```

When I render this json_string in my html element:

```
<div id='pixels_json' style='display:none'>
  {{ pixels_json|safe }}
</div>
```

This outputs as:

```
<div id='pixels_json' style='display:none'>
  ["<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->\r\n<script>\r\n!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?\r\nn.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;\r\nn.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;\r\nt.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,\r\ndocument,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');\r\nfbq('init', '325091591183913'); // Insert your pixel ID here.\r\nfbq('track', 'PageView'); fbq('track', 'Lead');\r\n</script>\r\n<noscript><img height=\"1\" width=\"1\" style=\"display:none\"\r\nsrc=\"https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=325091591183913&ev=PageView&noscript=1\"\r\n/></noscript>\r\n<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->\r\n<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->\r\n"]
</div>
```

Somehow, I am getting an error:

```
master:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

This is very strange because somehow the string is being evaluated even without me calling eval on it explicitly.

How can I pass store this string without triggering error from my browser?

Comment: I think I found my answer: I can put this inside a <textarea> and have it display to none

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow, I am getting an error:

If you render script tags, which you do in 'This outputs as', anything within those will be treated as script by the browser.

Comment: Ok, then how can I specifically not render script tags then?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? add the script later dynamically?

Comment: I am trying to add facebook pixels dynamically. So I am creating iframes and writing into them in run time.

Comment: I don't know enough about facebook pixels to tell what will happen, but the easiest way to run code on demand is to define the function within your own  JS and only call it when you need it. This code is designed to run immediately though. as an aside, the error is caused by \r\n which is the 'literal' for carriage return and newline.

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea style='display:none;' id='json_data'>
  {{ json_data }}
</textarea>


pixels = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json_data').innerText);
```

If it's textarea we are good to go!